# PyTorch: Tensors of the same index must be on the same device and the same dtype except `step` tensors that can be CPU and float32 notwithstanding

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to train a neural ODE network on Google Colab using PyTorch libraries. However, I am constantly getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Tensors of the same index must be on the same device and the same dtype except `step` tensors that can be CPU and float32 notwithstanding
```

The following is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/damage_neural/neural.py", line 370, in <module>
    optim.step()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 373, in wrapper
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 76, in _use_grad
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 163, in step
    adam(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 311, in adam
    func(params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 474, in _multi_tensor_adam
    grouped_tensors = Optimizer._group_tensors_by_device_and_dtype(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 397, in _group_tensors_by_device_and_dtype
    return _group_tensors_by_device_and_dtype(tensorlistlist, with_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_foreach_utils.py", line 42, in _group_tensors_by_device_and_dtype
    torch._C._group_tensors_by_device_and_dtype(tensorlistlist, with_indices).items()
RuntimeError: Tensors of the same index must be on the same device and the same dtype except `step` tensors that can be CPU and float32 notwithstanding
```

The error occurs at the `optim.step()` line in the following code excerpt:

```py
for epoch in tqdm(range(n_epochs)):
        optim.zero_grad()
        r = ode.odeint_adjoint(model, y[0],t,block_size=time_chunk_size)
        # loss_val = loss(r[...,0], y[...,0]) + loss(r[...,1], y[...,1]) + loss(r[...,2], y[...,2]) + loss(r[...,3], y[...,3])
        loss_val = loss(r, y)
        loss_hist.append(loss_val.cpu().detach().numpy())
        loss_val.backward()
------> optim.step()
        writer.add_scalar('Loss', loss_val, epoch)
        if loss_val < best_loss:
            best_loss = loss_val
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model.pt')
```

I have ensured that all my data are on the same device too:

```py
    d1 = (data_list[1] - torch.min(data_list[1])) / (torch.max(data_list[1]) - torch.min(data_list[1])).cuda()
    d2 = (data_list[3] - torch.min(data_list[3])) / (torch.max(data_list[3]) - torch.min(data_list[3])).cuda()
    d3 = (data_list[5] - torch.min(data_list[5])) / (torch.max(data_list[5]) - torch.min(data_list[5])).cuda()
    d4 = (data_list[6] - torch.min(data_list[6])) / (torch.max(data_list[6]) - torch.min(data_list[6])).cuda()
    d5 = (data_list[7] - torch.min(data_list[7])) / (torch.max(data_list[7]) - torch.min(data_list[7])).cuda()
    d6 = (data_list[16] - torch.min(data_list[16])) / (torch.max(data_list[16]) - torch.min(data_list[16])).cuda()

    # Create the state variable
    y = torch.stack([d2, d4, d3, d6]).cuda() # 4 x 39 x 1000
    y = y.permute(2,1,0).cuda() # 1000 x 39 x 4

    t = t.permute(1,0).cuda()

    d5= d5.permute(1,0).cuda()
    d1 = d1.permute(1,0).cuda()

    # Create the model
    model = NeuralODEModel(w_in, b_in, w_hid, b_hid, w_out, b_out, d5, d1, t).to(device)
    
    # Integrate the ODE
    r = ode.odeint_adjoint(model, y[0],t,block_size=time_chunk_size).cuda() # 1000 x 39 x 4

    r = r.permute(1,0,2).cuda() # 39 x 1000 x 4
```

When I initially ran this on a Linux machine, it seemed to work alright. But on Google Colab, after importing all the required libraries and files, I am getting the following error. How do I solve this error?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a PyTorch bug: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensors-of-the-same-index-must-be-on-the-same-device-and-the-same-dtype-except-step-tensors-that-can-be-cpu-and-float32-notwithstanding/190335.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem, and the optimizer I used is also adam

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this from the file:

```
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.bfloat16)
```